# Deploying a Symfony project with Jenkins: Best Practices

Tags: jenkins, symfony

I manage a few Symfony 2/3 projects on my Jenkins server that I am deploying to a live server. This is my current setup:

## The build

- checkout using git plugin
- remove database, if exists
- executing `composer install` (prod mode, optimize autoloader)
- executing `bower install` to fetch my assets
- executing a `gulp` build, that minifies and concatenates css / javascript (We don't use assetic)
- executing my database creation stuff
- executing unit tests

## The archiving

After the build, I **archive the artifacts** of the build without the `vendor`, `node_modules` and `bower_components` folders as a zip file using the "[Compress Artifacts](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Compress+Artifacts+Plugin)" Plugin.

## The deployment

I use the "[Promoted builds](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin)" plugin and the "[Publish over SSH](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin)" plugin in combination: If I want to "go live" with a build, I publish the artifacts (my zip file) over SSH to my live system in a directory called `staging_dir`. After the file upload, I execute some SSH commands:

- Set the live system to maintenance mode
- unzip the artifacts zip in my `staging_dir`
- execute `composer install` on the live system (same config as during the build)
- (`bower install` and the `gulp` build is not necessary, as we use the assets we created during the build)
- migrate database
- move the current live system files to a `backup` folder
- copy over the files from the `staging_dir`
- Set the live system to "production" mode (disable maintenance mode)

## Best practices?

I would now like to collect some best practices for deployment:

- Do you prefer to transfer the `vendor` folder to the live system instead of executing `composer install` there again?
- What about the assets? Do you `bower install` and `gulp` build on the live system again or do you use the published assets?
- How do you handle your passwords when executing a live promotion?
- ... other things I have forgotten.

Comment: David, I'm struggling with a quite similar setup. How do you send over SSH the zip file produced by "Compress Artifacts" plugin. It is stored in the root of each build and by default Publish plugin looks for files in workspace directory. How do you select the automatically zip file?

Comment: Could you please post your Jenkinsfile? It would be a really great example for other people who are just beginning to learn Jenkins.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Me and a couple of colleagues have been dealing with this for quite a while now. When we started it was quite hard to find good posts regarding this topic. This is why I'd like to share what we've found to be working "best" for us.

## Project details

One of our clients has a big and heavy platform used for managing his business process (something like an ERP & CRM). The platform has been initially developed using Symfony 2 and we've now upgraded to Symfony 3. To be sure everything is working properly the project has tons of test cases. We also use:

1. [Doctrine Migrations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html) so we could safely update the database on the production servers whenever this is necessary.
2. [Phing](https://www.phing.info/) / [Deployer](https://deployer.org/)
3. Bower
4. Assetic
5. PHPUnit
6. Git
7. Jenkins

## Testing

Once somebody commits to our git server, a hook lets Jenkins know and a build is triggered. Once the job finishes successfully we manually trigger the deployment. This is done by logging into the client's machine(s) and triggering a script we've developed.

## Deployment

We used to approach this the same way as you - upload the archive after jenkins finishes the job. This, however, proved to be quite problematic because in some cases the archive might get broken (i.e. due to network connection issues between the jenkins instance and the production server). Also it took considerably longer to upload a file from our server to the client's server. This is why we decided to use git and pull the necessary version from there. Using git proved to be more reliable and ensures you have an absolute copy of the project on the client's side. Also, rolling back to previous version is just one `git checkout` away :)

Because most of us already had experience with `ant` and `php` we have decided to use [Phing](https://www.phing.info/) and create a build script and automate most of the regular tasks. In the build script we've added most of the common tasks we run all the time such as install, upgrade, clear cache, install assets, etc. Then we made this script available on each production server.

Once the jenkins build job is successful and we've manually released & tagged the version of the product, we'd run `phing update` on the client's machine via SSH (this step could have been automated but was intentionally **not** due to some project requirements). What this command would do is:

1. Get the latest tagged version from our git server
2. If the **current** version < **latest** tagged version (with hash `19a6d9`) proceeds to next step
3. `phing maintenance:on` (sets the platform in an offline mode)
4. `git fetch origin 19a6d9`
5. `git checkout 19a6d9`
6. `phing composer:install`
7. `phing database:upgrade` (which runs a couple of commands, including database backup and `doctrine:migrations:migrate`)
8. `phing assets` (runs `bower install`, `assetic` commands and compiles all js/css into `one.css` and `one.js`)
9. `phing cache:clean`
10. `phing maintenance:off` (turns the platform on)

Our `phing update` task is also surrounded by `trycatch` and in case the update phase hits a brick it would automatically go into the rollback phase. It is done via a `phing rollback PREVIOUS_VERSION` command which does:

1. `git checkout PREVIOUS_VERSION` - restores the fs to the previous git version
2. `phing composer:install`
3. `phing database:rollback PREVIOUS_VERSION`
4. `phing assets`
5. `phing report` (this reports there's an issue with the upgrade to our issue tracker with a log file attached)

## Answers to your questions

1. Do you prefer to transfer the `bower_components` and the `vendor` folder to the live system instead of executing `bower install` and `composer install` there again?

   - I would go with `bower install` and `composer install`, because after the first time you'll already have everything cached. Every next run would be almost instantaneous or at least much faster than re-uploading all assets again and again via ftp. That might save you somewhat bandwidth and most importantly **time**. If you choose to do a similar setup to mine, you might want to avoid `compiling` the js/css on the Jenkins instance as you'll be doing that on the prod server.
2. How do you handle your passwords when executing a live promotion?

   - Not sure what you're asking?

## Conclusion

The setup mainly depends on your project requirements, the resources you have available (i.e. vps, shared hosting, git, ssh, etc) and your release process. As you can see, our deployment is slightly different from what you're doing. This doesn't make it bad nor good - it just suits our needs. If what you already have works for you and solves all of your problems - you should stick with it and try to optimize it. In case you're just getting started this is what you should be most careful about:

1. **FULL**... **BACKUPS**! Having a backup of the production filesystem is great, but you should also have a backup of the database. During the development course of your project it's likely you'd have new features which change the database. Some of those changes may be backwards incompatible. So be sure to backup everything or you might end up having a fs backup without a db to work with thus not being able to rollback.
2. Rollback - create a script which does all necessary steps to rollback the project to the previous version. If you're under a lot of pressure or things are time sensitive you might unintentionally make a mistake and break the backup or something else... Therefore make a script which does this for you.
3. Test the deployment process locally or on a testing machine to be sure everything really works before doing it on the actual production server.

I hope this helps you find the best solution to your release & deployment process. If you happen to find a better solution, please post it as an answer - it will definitely be helpful!

Comment: [Magallanes](http://magephp.com/) works nice for deployment. It creates a directory `releases` and a `current` symlink pointing to latest release. Rollback is fast and you don't need any offline time for your project cause all the processes like composer install, cache clear etc. are done in a separate directory and the symlink is updated at the end.

Comment: Yes, Magallanes ([Deployer](http://deployer.org/), etc) - they all work fine as well for backing up the file system. I would always try to use `git`, though, because you can be absolutely sure the fs is the same as the specified revision/version without fearing of corrupted files. There is little to no time cost when using git to revert. The bigger problem here is the database - the bigger it is, the longer it takes to rollback (and even longer if you're restoring from an `.sql` file)

Comment: Looking around for resources that this Q/A touches on perfectly, for all the hype surrounding CI/CD there's very little information actually available. Thanks for sharing your experience tftd. I was pondering whether to pack the project and then copy over completely until reading this and agree with the sentiments

Comment: I'm glad you find this answer helpful. Please feel free to add an answer to the question, should you find a better approach! :)